# What mechanism causes enemies to respawn?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

When looking around for enemies to kill (especially when doing dodge training), it gets a bit cumbersome when they're all dead. What can I do to force enemies to respawn? Is it a timed thing? Should I reset my system? Does traveling a certain distance away force them to come back?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have a concrete answer regarding Paper Jam, the previous game of the series did have a 20-enemy queue system where defeated enemies would respawn after 20 more non-boss battles are won. Don't quote me on this, but it's possible that Paper Jam uses the same 20-enemy queue system.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll wait for someone to verify this before accepting, but that's certainly a neat way to do it.